# Can't select $(this).[elements of TD] and append it to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the contents of the td="description" heading/title on the right of the image - in a table cell.

And add it underneath the img and continue the flow the same as before.

So far I have:

```
<script>
$('tr').each(function() {

 var desc = $(this).$('td.description').html() 
  $(this).$('td.image').append(desc);
  $('td.description').remove();


  });
 $("table#shopping-cart-items tr td.image").after($('<td id="clearSpace"></td>'));
 });


  </script>
```

IF I take "this" out - it correctly grabs it and appends it - but all the names are the same; so my use of $(this) I assume is breaking it i've also added the $('tr').each function?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why not just build the HTML the way you want it to be right off the bat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `$(this)` properly,

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  var desc = $('td.description', this).html() 
  $('td.image', this).append(desc);
  $('td.description', this).remove();
});
```

Your way of traversing is wrong. By default there is no function named `$` under jquery wrapper object. That is why your code is breaking.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - apologies; I get confused on the variation and how to use this correctly..

Comment: @MikeVanStan, if you read the API you'd know to use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), or `$(selector, context)` (which is an alias of `$(this).find(selector)`).

Comment: @MikeVanStan Glad to help!

Comment: @MikeVanStan Yes, `$("selector",context)` will be invoked internally when you call `.find()` You would come to know about it when you have a look at the source code of jQuery.

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes before accepting! Thanks again! I'll read up more

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the `each` function refers to the currently being iterated item matched by `$('tr')`. In your case you would have two ways to go with:

- `$('td.description', this)`: matches with all `td.description` elements existing inside the `this` element.
- `$(this).find('td.description')`: same as above.